# Ubuntu Telnet problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, telnet

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04. I am a student of microcomputer systems and networks.

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 and when trying to connect to `localhost` with `telnet`, the following happens:

```
$ telnet localhost
Connection closed with foreign host
```

Comment: You should show the exact command that you are using to make the connection. Also mention what you expect to happen. Is there or should there be anything listening for a telnet connection on the port that you connect to?

Comment: Use 'telnet localhost', i hope to start sessión in telnet.

Comment: Do you have a Telnet server installed? (Most modern operating systems do not install Telnet servers by default.)

Comment: telnet localhost will connect you your local system on port 23 by default unless you mentioned port no., like telnet localhost 22

Comment: Yes, i have instaled Telnet and the port used for Telnet is 23.

Comment: then open port no. 23 on your firewall

Comment: And what about your `/etc/hosts.deny`? Are you running `SELinux`?

Comment: maybe the telnet is not running. to check run `netstat -an |grep 23`

Comment: @SivaPrasath telnet is already running as confirmed from the nature of error message.

Comment: Telnet is functional, but i don't understand because no connect with localhost... i have other virtual machine of Ubuntu that works perfectly

Comment: Is that the *exact* error message you see?  Which version of `telnet` is installed?  Run `update-alternatives --display telnet`.

Comment: The version of Telnet is 0.17.

Comment: That suggests you're using netkit telnet.  Netkit telnet should display the message `Connection closed by foreign host.`, not `with`.  Please paste the *complete* output:  the exact command that you run, and *all* the lines that follow it.  There may be something else there that shows the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Open port no. 23 on ufw by giving below command :

```
sudo ufw allow 23
```

If ufw is not installed then first install it by issuing below command and then try again the above command :

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

Now, you can connect with `telnet localhost`

Comment: I do what you say and nothing :(

Comment: cal you telnet localhost 22?

Comment: It is rare for firewalls to block local connections to `localhost`.

Comment: @Mireia are you getting Protocal mismatch before connection closed by foreign host?

Comment: that means you are getting connected, once you will type something after that, it will give 'Protocol Mismatch' and pressing Enter key several time will give 'Connection closed by foreign host'. This is actually not a problem. It works like that.

Comment: I think so, i am not secure, but I should go out loggin telnet.. how upload screenshots here?

Comment: @Mireia [Don't upload screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) -- use a code block if you can.

Comment: Qué debo hacer para poner un bloque de código

Comment: Presione la tecla Control + K y luego escriba su mensaje de error